# how to get a full length serialized condition in 'salesrule' table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, conditions-serialized

how to get a full length  serialized condition in  'salesrule' table in  magento 2

> Table: salesrule

[image]

> code

```
 public function getRule()
    {
        $ruleModel = $this->_ruleFactory->create()->load(10);
        $conditionSerialized =$ruleModel->getConditionsSerialized();
        return $conditionSerialized;
    }
```

> output

[image]

> unserialized condition also does not appear full condition

```
return unserialize($conditionSerialized);
```

[image]

Comment: May i know why do you want this content?

Comment: For apply a custom discount based on this condition https://prnt.sc/oyjsgf

Comment: So you want to check the current cart items meet with your cart rule...right?

Comment: yes, current cart item will  have  a discount  based on cart price rule

Comment: You can get applied cart rule ids.....from quote table. from here you can apply custom discount here

Comment: I have actually applied a  custom discount in cart  now i want to  unserialize a data stored in db

Comment: a serialized condition is too large but i can able to serialized a some of the data i cant serialized  a large size of  condition_serialized data

Comment: Just echo without unserialize, did you get all of data?